How to achieve internal shadow effect on Android
The shadow effect of this image is what I want to achieve
enter image description here
I tried using a layer list, but the results were not ideal.
I would like to ask how to achieve an inner shadow effect similar to the image above
This is my code:
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- background color -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/color_ECF1F9" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!--  left shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:centerColor="#004274F4"
                android:centerX="0.95"
                android:endColor="#854274F4"
                android:startColor="@color/color_ECF1F9" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!--  right shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="360"
                android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
                android:centerX="0.95"
                android:endColor="#854274F4"
                android:startColor="#00FF0000" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!--  top shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
                android:centerY="0.06"
                android:endColor="#00FF0000"
                android:startColor="#854274F4" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!--  top shadow -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:centerColor="#00FF0000"
                android:centerY="0.06"
                android:endColor="#00FF0000"
                android:startColor="#854274F4" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>


I wouldn't use an XML drawable.  I'd use an image as the drawable.  XML drawables are really only meant for very simple things.  THis is already beyond the normal usecase.  A vector drawable might work as well if you want a smaller size (at the cost of CPU time while drawing)
